# Why is my Ajax Form submit not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I am working on this laravel 5 app and I can't seem to figure out why my Ajax call is not working for this particular form because it has been working well for other forms. Sample code below.

```
{!! Form::model($training, ['url' => 'trainings/' . $training->id,
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'id' => 'edit_training_form', 
    'role' => 'form']) !!}
  // Form body
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Ajax Call Sample code below:

```
            $("document").ready(function() {

                $("#edit_academic_form").on('submit', updateAcademic);
                $("#edit_training_form").on('submit', updateTraining);
            }


        function ajaxCall(context) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                data: context.serialize(),
                url:  context.attr('action'),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".validation-errors").hide().empty();
                    $(".success-message").hide().empty();
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $(".success-message").append(data.message).show();
                    $(".success-message").delay( 2000 ).fadeOut();
                },
                error: function(data){
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    console.log(errors);
                    // Render errors with JS
                    $.each(errors, function(index, value)
                    {
                        if (value.length != 0)
                        {
                            $(".validation-errors").append('<li>'+ value +'</li>');
                        }
                    });
                    $(".validation-errors").show();
                }
            });
        }

    function updateTraining(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ajaxCall($(this))
    }

function updateAcademic(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ajaxCall($(this))
}
```

The call for updateAcademic is working pretty well but updateTraining is not working. Firebug does not show any error. It's kind of doing some direct form submit. I have cleared browser cache to make sure the js is being read, change browser but no result. Looking at the source of the code from my browser the form is well defined (id is ok) as shown below:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/trainings/1" 
  accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal"
  id="edit_training_form" role="form">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="QvvgMIWZN1VYGUOF2zGE8ALgVnAYaZUS5SseW4i5">
</form>
```

**Edit**
Firebug does not give any error. I have my controller like so:

```
public function update(UpdateTrainingRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $this->training->save_training($data, $id);
        $result['message'] = "Training Updated Successfully";
        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

When I hit save all I get is a blank browser page with the message:

{"message":"Training Updated Successfully"} suggesting the form is posting directly.

Appreciate help

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: I get no error @NiranjanNRaju. Look at the edited part of the question.

Comment: where is `trainings` function??

Comment: Which trainings are you talking about?

Comment: Ok I see. I am have my route like so Route::put('trainings/{trainings}', 'TrainingsController@update');

Comment: your form post is to `trainings`, im asking about that.

Comment: instead of `return`, `echo` the data.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I don't think that is the problem. I have been using this same implementation and everything has been working fine. Anyway I get this after echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 09:03:35 GMT {"message":"Training Updated Successfully"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93141/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-fokwa-best).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my js. My js look like so:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    limitCharacters();
    $("#edit_academic_form").on('submit', updateAcademic);
    $("#edit_training_form").on('submit', updateTraining);
}
```

The function limitCharacters() had some syntax errors thus preventing the codes beneath it from ever getting called hence reason why the Ajax didn't work. I resolved issues in limitCharacters and now everything is working fine.